# 2 Foreign keys in the same class to 1 primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a table called **Pages** which has a primary Key of *PageID*. I want to use the following model to make at table called **PageMap** which gets the current and next *PageID* (one is going to be a link) but I keep getting an error with the foreign key. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class PageMap
{
    public int PageMapID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Page Visible On")]
    public int PageID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Question")]
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("PageID")]
    [DisplayName("Link to Page")]
    public int NextPageID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Ordering")]
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public virtual Pages Pages { get; set; }
    public virtual Questions Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the name of the entity in foreign key attribute.i.e 
    [ForeignKey("Page")]